# Como sacar el resultado con decimales

Tags: javascript

Estoy con una duda que a muchos les parecerá simple, quiero que mi resultado salga con decimales, intente declarar la variable como rango=0.0, tambien intente con parseFloat.Fixed, pero no me resulta sigue lanzandome el resultado sin decimales.

```
const lista=[
    1,
    3,
    8,
    10,
    5,
    3
];


function calcularRangomedio(lista){
    listaorde = lista.sort(function(a,b){
        return a-b;
    });
    var rango = 0.0;
    rango=parseFloat(listaorde[0])+parseFloat(listaorde[listaorde.length-1])/2;
    return rango;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu resultado no devuelve decimales, porque te está devolviendo un número entero.

Debido a la prioridad de las operaciones, lo que tú estás haciendo en tu función es:

***1 + (10 / 2) = 6***

Ya que la división se ejecuta antes que la suma. Sospecho que lo que tú quieres hacer es:

***(1 + 10) / 2 = 5,5***

Por lo que debes cambiar el cálculo de la variable `rango` para que contemple esto

```js
const lista=[
    1,
    3,
    8,
    10,
    5,
    3
];

console.log(calcularRangomedio(lista));


function calcularRangomedio(lista){
    const listaorde = lista.sort(function(a,b){
        return a-b;
    });
    const rango = (listaorde[0] + listaorde[listaorde.length-1]) / 2;
    
    return rango;
}
```

**EDIT:** Si aunque el resultado no tenga decimales, quieres forzar a que te lo devuelva siempre, con por ejemplo 2, puedes usar la función `toFixed()` que tienen los tipo ***number***.

```js
const lista=[
    1,
    3,
    8,
    10,
    5,
    3
];

console.log(calcularRangomedio(lista));


function calcularRangomedio(lista){
    const listaorde = lista.sort(function(a,b){
        return a-b;
    });
    const rango = (listaorde[0] + listaorde[listaorde.length-1]) / 2;
    
    return rango.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Los números en js ya son números de punto flotante de por si, en tu caso al ser enteros no agrega el decimal `.0`. Si lo que estas buscando es que agregue el decimal por más que sea entero vas a tener que tratarlo como un string

```js
console.log('Convirtiendo el numero 10 para que muestre decimales: ', (10).toFixed(1))
console.log('Convirtiendo el numero 10.002: ', (10.002).toFixed(1))
```

El parámetro que se pasa a `toFixed` indica cuantos decimales querés mostrar. Notar en el segundo ejemplo que `toFixed` trunca el valor a la cantidad de decimales que indiques mostrar.